# Merge multiple EntityTypeIDs

Tags: api, bing-maps

I have a

```
requestUrl = "https://spatial.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/data/Microsoft/PointsOfInterest?spatialFilter=nearby(lat,lon,rad)&$filter=EntityTypeID%20eq%20'7947',EntityTypeID%20eq%20'4581',EntityTypeID%20eq%20'9535',EntityTypeID%20eq%20'4013',EntityTypeID%20eq%20'4170'&$select=EntityID,DisplayName,Latitude,Longitude,__Distance&$top=4&key=Key";
```

which doesn't work whereas

```
requestUrl = "https://spatial.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/data/Microsoft/PointsOfInterest?spatialFilter=nearby(lat,lon,rad)&$filter=EntityTypeID%20eq%20'7947'&$select=EntityID,DisplayName,Latitude,Longitude,__Distance&$top=4&key=Key";
```

does work.

How do I merge multiple EntityTypeIDs?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `And` or `Or` between your queries, not commas. You can see this in the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/spatial-data-services/query-api/query-options

So try the following;

```
requestUrl = "https://spatial.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/data/Microsoft/PointsOfInterest?spatialFilter=nearby(lat,lon,rad)&$filter=EntityTypeID%20eq%20'7947'%20Or%20EntityTypeID%20eq%20'4581'%20Or%20EntityTypeID%20eq%20'9535'%20Or%20EntityTypeID%20eq%20'4013'%20Or%20EntityTypeID%20eq%20'4170'&$select=EntityID,DisplayName,Latitude,Longitude,__Distance&$top=4&key=Key";
```